# When to use -ComputerName and when -ConnectionUri?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

In my quest of learning PowerShell I stumbled across something that confuse me.
I don't really understand why sometime I have to use

```
New-PSSession -ComputerName "servername"
```

and sometime instead

```
New-PSSession -ConnectionUri "http://FQDN/powershell" etc...
```

I couldn't find a clear explanation of the two approaches. What is exactly the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`New-PSSession` is working over PSremoting, which should be configured before use. Configuration means that you can do it slightly differently for each of the computers. The simplest examples are different ports an different endpoint names. Uri format is as follows: `<Transport>://<ComputerName>:<Port>/<ApplicationName>`

For default configuration you need to pass only `ComputerName` and default values will be taken for all the other values.

If, however, you have non default configuration, you have a choice:

- Pass `ConnectionURI` with all the data
- Use`ComputerName`, together with `UseSSL`, `Port`, and `ApplicationName`parameters to specify the ConnectionURI values.

So it's just 2 ways of passing the same information to command.

In your example you could do:

```
New-PSSession -ConnectionUri "http://FQDN/powershell"
```

or

```
New-PSSession -ComputerName "FQDN" -UseSSl $false -ApplicationName "powershell"
```

Both will behave exactly the same

Comment: I start to understand a bit. Just to clarify, I can connect to my exchange server as -computername exchange.domain.local or as -connectionuri http://etc etc. What change is the configuration of the powershell enviroment?

Comment: Typically is only Exchange that have a peculiar PS setting or there are other common cases where I need to use non default configuration?

Comment: There's no need to use one or the other. `ComputerName` with parameters is more strongly typed, the `ConnectionURI` is shorter